# Is it possible to embed a PDF doc at the end of XSL FO?

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I have used the below  tag

```
<fox:external-document src="Resources/test.pdf" />
```

But Its throwing the below error.

> Apr 03, 2017 10:15:31 AM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener
>   processEvent SEVERE: Image not available. URI: Resources/test.pdf.
>   Reason: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file
>   format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for
>   Resources/test.pdf (No context info available)
>   org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is
>   not supported. No ImagePreloader found for Resources/test.pdf     at
>   org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageManager.preloadImage(ImageManager.java:180)

I have kept the namespace properly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using fop 2.1 and include pdf as external-graphics successfully using the [FOP PDF Images Plugin](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fop-pdf-images.html)

> "The four jar files should be placed in the lib directory of your fop
>   installation"

I'm think my download was from [here](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/xmlgraphics/binaries/fop-pdf-images-2.1.0.SNAPSHOT-bin.tar.gz).

Comment: @rahul-johny, did that help with you question?

Comment: It's only two jar files now.